# Проверить статус mysql через exec (php) не получается

Tags: php, debian, ssh, mysql

Здравствуйте
У меня vps на debian. Возникла необходимость узнать через php status mysql. Соответственно, запускаю:

```
echo exec('/usr/sbin/service mysql status');
```

Выдает

```
MySQL is stopped..
```

При этом если этот же код

```
/usr/sbin/service mysql status
```

запустить из консоли, выдает нормальную статистику (пока работаю, mysql включен).

Как такое возможно? Почему он не ругается как-либо, а выдает некорректные данные? И, собственно, что делать, как это исправить?

Помогите, пожалуйста, очень надо.

UPD. Мне нужно запускать SH, а не что-либо другое

Вопрос закрыт, обошла его с другой стороны. Как говорится - пока не спросишь кого-нибудь, сама нифига не поймешь, как исправить. Тот факт, что ответы пришли вообще не в кассу, тут значения не имеет.

Comment: Я надеюсь это вам чем-то поможет: [mysql_stat()][1]

Да и мне кажется костыли тут не совсем уместны :)


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-stat.php

Comment: Забудьте про функции exec, eval. Лучше их вообще запретите на уровне php.ini, безопаснее будет, в случае если на сервер зальют шел, хоть не смогут выполнять системные функции.

Comment: Да. Судя по английской StackExchange, давать ответы на свой вопрос - приветствуется.

Answer (score 1):

Интересно, что пишет stopped... Скорее всего прав не хватает.

```
$  /usr/sbin/service mysql status
[info] MySQL (Percona Server) is stopped..
```

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/service mysql status
[info] /usr/bin/mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.6.15, for Linux on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2009-2013 Percona LLC and/or its affiliates
Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Server version      5.6.15-63.0
Protocol version    10
Connection      Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         3 days 1 hour 45 min 34 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 133835  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 12287  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 252  Queries per second avg: 0.504.
```

Если так?

```
exec('sudo /usr/sbin/service mysql status', $result);
var_dump($result);
```

Ещё есть [mysql-stat](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-stat.php) функция. Может вас устроит.

А как обошли? Интересно же)